Different methods for Godel numbering
What are the different ways to construct a godel number?
Reading different books on godels incompleteness theorem , i noticed that there are different ways to make a godel number.
That made me wonder what are all different options?
What is the most compact one?
What is the most (human) readable one? What are other options.
What is your favourite?
What are the advantages/disadvantages of different coding schemes?

Hi! This seems totally opinion based. To make it less so, perhaps you can give some context to guide fitness for a specific purpose.

There are a lot of different options for numberings. Some standard (e.g. Gödel's), some nice (e.g. Smullyan's [1]), some weird (e.g. self-referential) and some bad ones (e.g. deviant).
Let me add on the last two examples: Self-referential numberings allow you to prove ''directly'' the strong diagonal lemma (see [2]). The deviant numbering allow you to refute some of our usual metamathematical theorems (see [3]).
Your questions are a bit too vague to answer precisely, but here is a list that might interest you and hopefully answers some of your questions:

The most standard one is Gödel's original numbering which encode any finite sequence of symbols based on prime factorization.

The length-first lexicographic numbering gives you a bijection between the Kleene star of the alphabet $A^\ast$ and the natural numbers.

One numbering I like is simply to use Gödel's $\beta$-function for the whole arithmetization (see [4]).

If you're working in a weak theory of arithmetic then some numberings are more suitable than others. Typically, Gödel's numbering is a bad choice if you use a theory such as $\sf I\Delta_0$ for which exponentiation is not provably total. In such context, Smullyan's one which uses a representation in base $b$ or the like are more common.


[1] R. M. Smullyan. Theory of Formal Systems. Princeton University Press, 1961.
[2] B. Grabmayr and A. Visser. ‘Self-Reference Upfront: A Study of Self-Referential Gödel Numberings’. In: Review of Symbolic Logic 16.2 (2023), pp. 385–424.
[3] B. Grabmayr. ‘On the Invariance of Gödel’s Second Theorem with Regard to Numberings’. In: The Review of Symbolic Logic 14.1 (2021), pp. 51–84.
[4] A. Bezboruah and J. C. Shepherdson. ‘Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem for Q’. In: The Journal of Symbolic Logic 41.2 (1976), pp. 503–512.
